# What is an amateur soccer game between friends called in English? ('Pelada' in Portuguese)

Tags: word-request, phrase-request

In Portuguese, we have an expression: "Peladeiro de fim de semana". It's like "weekend soccer player" or "an amateur soccer game that happens between friends", for this expressions we also say "Pelada" in Portuguese which is a very informal term. It's translate literally to "naked" in Portuguese. Of course I think "naked soccer player" shouldn't have the same meaning in English. But is there an informal expression to say "an amateur soccer game that happens between friends" in English?

Comment: Sunday Morning footballer. Or Sunday League footballer. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sunday_league_football It's not quite the same as a game between friends, but it has the feel of "grass-roots" football where enthusiasm and tradition are more important than quality. Read about Hackney Marshes an area of London where some 80 pitches are used for this kind of football.

Comment: In the US, the question is, "What is a soccer game?"  :-)

Comment: It is not soccer/football specific, but  **pick-up game** might work. [link](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&source=web&rct=j&url=http://www.urbandictionary.com/define.php%3Fterm%3Dpick-up%2520game&ved=0ahUKEwjTguKil6rSAhXIYyYKHa59BVQQFggvMAM&usg=AFQjCNHrsxd7KXA9TYU_t82cbxiE1RrCkw&sig2=7CDxc5T3058M9Z4zzZaPCg)

Comment: thanks! and how could we call the player who playes this type of game?

Comment: I have no clue,-- friends,  players..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If it's organised, it's *Sunday morning football* in the UK, because such matches are usually played then.

If it's casual, we in Britain would call it a *friendly game*, not to be confused with organised friendly matches in professional and semi-professional football.

In America, they use the term *pick-up game* for all sorts of sports.